# Best software for showing SQL Server Database Structure

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, diagram

I have a MSSQL2005 DB with about 140 tables.  I want to create either an accessible diagram or a printable API type document with the table structure.  Is there a program that offers this kind of db visualization?

I find the diagramming built into SQL Server to be very clunky and very inaccessible for my DB size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm).

Comment: SQL Doc was perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I always used Visio for this type of thing.

Comment: Visio 2013 doesn't have the option to reverse engineer. So for 2013 this is impossible. Don't know why Microsoft rewmoved it though. It was really useful... Oh well...

Answer (score 2):

I like Toad Data Modeler for this.  It reverse-engineers Microsoft SQL Server databases (and other brands of databases too), but more than that, you can start making your modeling changes inside the tool and it'll generate change scripts.

If you use somebody else's tool, make sure that you can round trip changes - meaning, if you put all the time and effort into getting your documentation right, and then you change the database inside SQL, can you re-import your changes from the database without overwriting your work in the documentation tool?  Most of 'em don't do that, but Toad Data Modeler does.

(Disclaimer - I work for Quest.  I used this program before Quest bought it, though, and always loved it.)

http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/

Comment: This tool is good, but works only on Windows. Is there any tool for Mac or Linux?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The enterprise database design market is pretty Windows-centric.